# Lock when power button is pressed in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, power, power-management, microsoft-surface

I have a surface, and it's getting very irritating when it sleeps when I press the power button.  Since I use it mostly as a tablet, I'd like it to behave as one, and lock when I press power.

Comment: Have you done any research on this ?

Comment: How come your research didn't find [Change what happens when you press the power button on your computer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-what-happens-when-you-press-the-power-button-on-your-computer)

Answer (score 0):

what you want exactly, seems to be impossible.
if you are sure it goes to 'sleep mode' and not 'hibernate' there is no better solution as far as i can tell.

you want it to just lock the screen, like a tablet, by pressing the power button. you can't do that. but setting it to ask for a password on wake-up from sleep is nearly the same. please make sure it does that.

1. go to power options

[image: (see picture)]

2. on the left, there's an option to "choose what my power buttons does" press it!
3. make sure the option is set to 'sleep'

[image: (Like this)]

Just to make it clear-

'Hibernate' saves the computer state on the hard-disk and shut down, which  takes a long time to wake up from.

'Sleep' saves on the RAM, and take the computer to a low power consumption state, which is way faster to wake-up from.

I barely can't feel the difference of pressing the button on my tablet vs. my computer, when in sleep-mode. (maybe my pc is very fast)

if you have all the setting set right, you can't come any closer to the tablet feeling.

I hope this answered your "question".

Comment: thank you Magicandre for the edit, i did oversee that option.

Comment: new users don't have the permissions to post pictures. you need some reputation to do this.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then , im working on that 